# resharper in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a license for Resharper and have it setup on Visual Studio 2012, we recently installed Visual Studio 2013 and I don't see resharper there, is there anyway to get it into Visual Studio 2013 as well?  We have resharper version 8.1 full edition.

Comment: I don't know about resharper specifically, but in general with Visual Studio you have to do everything in a specific order.  In this case, you probably need to re-install Resharper now that you have VS2013 installed as well...  and hope it doesn't break the existing installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the Resharper installation again and choose VS 2013 instance.